# How To Combine Two Json Values

Tags: json

I have a text file with several hundred json entries.The first two entries look like this

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "timestamp": "1565343832",
    "ports": [{
        "port": 80,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 245
    }]
}
```

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.2",
    "timestamp": "1565343837",
    "ports": [{
        "port": 81,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 43
    }]
}
```

I would like to parse this json file and combine the values for ip and port and put them in a text file.So the text file will have entries like this

```
127.0.0.1:80

127.0.0.2:81
```

How can this be done

Comment: `ip = entry["ip"] + ":" + str(entry["ports"][0]["port"])`? Combined with any one of the many questions about parsing JSON and looping over files

Comment: Those are separate questions: how to parse a json and access the values, how to concatenate values, how to write to a file. Also, how would this work if there are multiple ports in the "ports" array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ code example, use of boost::property_tree we can read json data and parse

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("entries.txt");
 for (/*for loop for each entry*/) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    //assign input values to ss per entry 
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
    std::string IP = pt.get<std::string>("ip");
    std::string PORT = pt.get<std::string>("ports.port");
    outfile << IP << ":" <<PORT;
}
```